# OpenCV медленно читает видео

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, видео

Использую стандартный код для чтения кадров из видео

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    /* обработка */
```

Но даже если я не произвожу какую либо обработку, то файл читается с реальной его скоростью воспроизведения. Например, 30 кадров в секунду.

Не могу понять, как можно заставить OpenCV читать файл с максимальной возможной скоростью?

Comment: Работаете в виндовс?

Comment: @eri, да. Windows 11

Comment: Точно не проводите обработку? А кодек, кстати, какой и какое железо? А то может у вас там сильно продвинутый кодек в этом видео (например, `H.264`), а железо слабенькое и оно еле успевает декодировать.

Comment: @CrazyElf, Проц 8/16 3,2 ГГц, 16 ОЗУ и 1660 Ti, M2 SSD. Кодек да, H.264. но железо думаю спокойно с ним справится. Та и оно не тормозит, а идет так, как будто бы просто воспроизведение. С такой же скоростью, как в плеере